# setAutoGrow: other pages should "shrink" again

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, autogrow

I'm using `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(7);` to grow my page (page=highscore table so needs to grow).

However, when I go back to other pages, the canvas stays grown, but it should adapt to the new content, off course... Basicly, it needs to shrink again.

I tried setSize but that didn't work.

Anyone who can help me? I've been looking for hours...
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: And in your other pages you’re using setAutoGrow as well?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this - shrink the canvas when you load a new page and then call setAutoGrow()

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({height:600});
setTimeout("FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()",500);
```

here is a full article describing the solution http://www.twistermc.com/36764/shrink-facebook-tabs/

Comment: Ha! Nice solutions! *facepalm for not thinking of it myself*. Here, have my +1

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() only grows the iframe. It never shrinks it down. I have been looking for a similar feature for a while but there's no documentation about shrinking the iframe. It would be nice if anyone came up with a function to do a sort of autoShrink().

Comment: or they just need to make FB.Canvas.AutoSize();  Now that would be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at my response above. I make the canvas smaller and then setAutoGrow() fixes it the way it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where SetAutoGrow was mis calculating only slightly because of a bottom margin on FB comments at the bottom of the page, resulting in a scrollBar.

Found myself writing my own building upon the above;

```
var mainContainer = $("#training");

var resizeTimer = setInterval(function () {

  // fix for FF to make setAutoGrow work.
  mainContainer.height('auto');
  var newHeight = mainContainer.height();
  mainContainer.height(newHeight);

  // fixes lack of auto shrink
  FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: newHeight });
}, 500);
```